# Create a folder with patch

Tags: svn, deployment, patch

We will be using patch files to apply changes to our live system.

However, I saw that when creating a patch from Tortoise any new folders created, are not included within the patch.

Maybe this is the way that patch works, but what is the strategy of applying patches that need to add or delete folders/files?

Say you create a patch file from 5 svn revisions. Do I need to track (in the svn log) any folder or files added/deleted and manually create/delete them on the live system before applying the patch?

Comment: I'm not sure that patch is the smartest way to update a live system.  If you mistakenly patch against the wrong version, or someone pushed the wrong file to the live system, then patch could end up breaking your system.  I think it is much smarter to use a tool like rsync, which will ensure that your live system is an exact mirror of your dev system.

Comment: The last time I did a search on this I came to the conclusion that add/delete files and folders are not reflected by a patch and should be done manually. patch only applies the diff on existing files. if you delete a file, patch only deletes the content of the file in destination folder but does not mark the file to be deleted from svn.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is a proper answer but I will give you my hunch on why the patch isn't creating your directories.

1. The patch should be *normally* created from the root of your application or main folder.
2. The patch should be applied in this same folder on the instance you want to update.

I think it should create your folders if you try it this way.

BTW, if you already use svn, why not update your live folder straight with svn, or even svn export if you don't want .svn folders on your live site? Much easier to maintain than manually patching.

Good-luck.

Comment: The thing is that when I create the patch, there is nothing in it mentioning the creation or deletion of a folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing one small step. You need to tell SVN about any files/folders you have added to your project. In Explorer, right-click on the folder to be added, then select TortoiseSVN -> Add... Now it will be included in any patches you create (see [Adding New Files And Directories](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-add.html) in the Tortoise SVN documentation). Furthermore, when the patch is applied, any new files/folder will be created - as you would expect.

Comment: The folder is added exactly as you describe, but it does not get included in the patch

Comment: What can i say...it should be included. Maybe run 'Clean up' on your working copy. Does the added folder have a big blue plus sign on it?

Comment: Hi. Yes. The folder has the blue icon. Can someone post a patch file sample, containing lines which create a folder?

Comment: I think I've realised what you are getting confused with: empty folders and empty files will not be included in the patch. Subversion itself doesn't support this.